# JS，Removes a specific element from the array that is consecutive the same

Tags: javascript

```js
var arry = [1,2,3,4,-1,-1,-1,-1,5,6,7,8,9,10];
console.log(arry.length)
for(let i=0; i<arry.length; i++){
 if(arry[i] === -1 ){
  arry.splice(i,i);
 }
}
console.log(arry)
```

How do you remove specific elements in a JS array，
I want to remove the -1 element。
but when arry = [-1,-1,-1,-1,5,6,7,8,9,10]，Become unavailable。

Answer (score 4):

Try not to mutate (`splice`) an array *while you're iterating over it* - the resulting behavior can be very confusing and unintuitive inside a `for` loop that's iterating over the indicies. Use `.filter` instead:

```js
var arry = [1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const removeConsecutive = arr => {
  let lastItem = undefined;
  return arr.filter((element) => {
    const keep = lastItem !== element;
    lastItem = element;
    return keep;
  });
};
console.log(removeConsecutive([1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
console.log(removeConsecutive([-1,-1,-1,-1,5,6,7,8,9,10]));
```

If you're trying to delete *all* `-1`s and not just repeated consecutive items, it's a bit simpler:

```js
var arry = [1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const removeConsecutive = arr => arr.filter(element => element !== -1);
console.log(removeConsecutive([1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]));
console.log(removeConsecutive([-1,-1,-1,-1,5,6,7,8,9,10]));
```

Comment: I think I understand. Thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, your question seemed to imply that the condition was having identical consecutive values - see edit

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

Briefly, your `splice` function change the array when you iterate through this array

think about this scenario:

var arr = [-1,-1,3]

when i=0, you splice arr[0] out(which is first -1)

now the arr become [-1, 3], and the loop process will check index 1, which is 3,

the second element just skipped

**Solution**

Just try to use filter as previous answer, or, you can just check all the element of array, and push elements that not equal to -1 to another array

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

According to your provided expected result I think you are talking about removing specific value from the array, which can be done by `.filter()`.

```
arry.filter((e)=>e!==-1);
```

here you feed a filter function `(element,index,array)=>{}` and return true for the elements you want it remained in the array. Here I use `!==` to filter out when element of value `-1`.